# c# MVC Html helper + expressions + remove the uglyness

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

Im trying to create an dropdownlist from an IList with following syntax:

```
@Html.DropDowntListFor(Model.VisitingAddresses, vistingAddress => vistingAddress.Id, vistingAddress => vistingAddress.Name)
```

This works with the following code:

```
public static IHtmlString DropDowntListFor
        <TModel>(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, IList<TModel> list, Expression<Func<TModel, string>> value, Expression<Func<TModel, string>> text)
    {
        var dropdownName = value.Parameters.First().Name;

        var selectedListItem = new List<SelectListItem>();

        var values = list.AsQueryable().Select(value).ToList();
        var texts = list.AsQueryable().Select(text).ToList();

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
        {
            selectedListItem.Add(new SelectListItem
                                     {
                                        Value = values[i],
                                        Text = texts[i]
                                     });
        }

        return htmlHelper.DropDownList(dropdownName, selectedListItem);
    }
```

But as you can see the code above (in the htmlhelper) is really really ugly, is there someone that knows an more beautiful way (in code) for in the html helper?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think that is ugly?

Comment: Filip Thanks for your response, did you look into my code? Im hardcoding the dropdownname picking the first with linq and then the name also list.AsQueryable() then a select, the for loop all this shouldn't be nessarry with some nice expressions?.

Comment: I see what you mean now when Jon posted his answer. I just think that your code is readable so imho it's not ugly. Maybe it's not optimized, but not ugly.

Comment: True, once creating the html helper no one will look into the code, so that is no problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you after something like this?

```
public static IHtmlString DropDowntListFor<TModel>
    (this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, IList<TModel> list, 
     Expression<Func<TModel, string>> valueSelector, 
     Expression<Func<TModel, string>> textSelector)
{
    var dropdownName = valueSelector.Parameters.First().Name;

    Func<TModel, string> compiledValueSelector = valueSelector.Compile();
    Func<TModel, string> compiledTextSelector = textSelector.Compile();

    var selectedListItem = list.Select(x => new SelectListItem {
                                           Value = compiledValueSelector(x),
                                           Text = compiledTextSelector(x) })
                               .ToList();

    return htmlHelper.DropDownList(dropdownName, selectedListItem);
}
```

Note that if you don't need the text selector as an expression tree, you can simplify it slightly further:

```
public static IHtmlString DropDowntListFor<TModel>
    (this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, IList<TModel> list, 
     Expression<Func<TModel, string>> valueSelectorExpression, 
     Func<TModel, string> textSelector)
{
    var dropdownName = valueSelector.Parameters.First().Name;

    var valueSelector = valueSelectorExpression.Compile();

    var selectedListItem = list.Select(x => new SelectListItem {
                                           Value = valueSelector(x),
                                           Text = textSelector(x) })
                               .ToList();

    return htmlHelper.DropDownList(dropdownName, selectedListItem);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```
@Html.DropDowntListForVisitingAddress(x => x.Id, x => x.Name)
```

and then because your view is already strongly typed to some model, `HtmlHelper` is already strongly typed => use this to fetch the model:

```
public static IHtmlString DropDowntListForVisitingAddress(
    this HtmlHelper<MyViewModel> html,
    Func<VisitingAddress, string> value,
    Func<VisitingAddress, string> text
)
{
    MyViewModel model = html.ViewData.Model;
    var values = model.VisitingAddresses.Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = value(x),
        Text = text(x)
    });
    var selectList = new SelectList(values, "Value", "Text");
    return html.DropDownListFor(
        x => x.SelectedAddress,
        selectList
    );
}
```

Comment: And how about the other 20 models that i have?

Comment: @daanl, have them implement a common interface or base view model. I hope you don't repeat this logic in your 20 other view models.

Comment: Im Not going to implement an Html helper into my view model

Comment: @DarinDimitrov With a common interface works only for helpers that are used for displaying data, otherwise an error will show-up with the text `Cannot create an instance of an Interface`. Anyway thanks for your answer! :)